# Accentuated characters not displaying well in Arcpy Toolbox in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-toolbox, internationalization

Accentuated are not well displayed in my Toolbox made with ArcPy.

For instance :

```
def __init__(self):
    """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
    self.label = "Sample éééé"
```

Produce the following output while executing from ArcMap :

`Sample Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã©`

`é` become `Ã©`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArcMap uses the following encoding `cp1252`

In order to make accentuated characters well displayed in ArcMap UI.

First add the following import and set encoding to `utf-8` at the beginning of your `.pyt` file.

```
import sys 
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

`reload` is needed because : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393758/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe5-in-position-0-ordinal

Then every string you display in the UI must be formated like this :

```
sampleString = "éééé"    
sampleString.encode('cp1252') #output : éééé
```

Comment: +1 I have just tested and found this to work.  I used `sampleString = "éééé".encode('cp1252')` rather than on two lines.

Comment: I am confused though @Marc_Alx, your link doesn't explain why `reload()` is needed that I can see?

Comment: Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python) could help on understanding the use of `reload`  though it seems that it's more a 'hack' than a solution due to potential side-effects.